# How to deserialize OkResult from the controller action

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I'm trying to create xUnit using mock tests for my API that uses the DataAccess layer for MongoDB. But for some reason, it just doesn't parse `OkResult` to JSON or BSON. I definitely know that there are 2 values that I need from the debugger:

[image: 2 Values to parse]

My model is:

```cs
namespace DataAccess.Models;
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class CyberGood
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("id")]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("insideOf")]
    public string? InsideOf { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("madeIn")]
    public string MadeIn { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("amount")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And my controller is:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CyberGoodController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ICyberGoodService _cyberGoodService;

    public CyberGoodController(ICyberGoodService cyberGoodService)
    {
        _cyberGoodService = cyberGoodService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllCyberGoodAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var cyberGoods = await _cyberGoodService.GetAllCyberGoodAsync();
            return Ok(cyberGoods);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

My test case:

```cs
[Fact]
[Obsolete]
public async Task GetAll_CyberGoods_ReturnsList()
{
    //Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<ICyberGoodService>();
    mock.Setup(d => d.GetAllCyberGoodAsync()).ReturnsAsync(GetTestCyberGoods());
    var service = new CyberGoodController(mock.Object);
    var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(type => ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type) 
    || type.FullName.StartsWith("DataAccess") 
    || type.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult")); 
    BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);

    //Act
    IActionResult result = await service.GetAllCyberGoodAsync();
    var bsonRes = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<CyberGood>>(result.ToBson());

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(GetTestCyberGoods().Count, bsonRes.Count);

}
```

But instead of some test result, it gives me this error:

> Message:  MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException : An error
> occurred while serializing the Value property of class
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult: Type
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[DataAccess.Models.CyberGood, DataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] is not configured as an allowed type for this instance of ObjectSerializer. ---- MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException : Type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[DataAccess.Models.CyberGood,
> DataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] is
> not configured as an allowed type for this instance of
> ObjectSerializer.
>
> Stack Trace: 
> BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeMember(BsonSerializationContext context, Object obj, BsonMemberMap memberMap) BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeClass(BsonSerializationContext
> context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TClass document)
> BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TClass value) IBsonSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value) ObjectSerializer.SerializeDiscriminatedValue(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value, Type actualType) ObjectSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value) DiscriminatedInterfaceSerializer`1.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext
> context, BsonSerializationArgs args, TInterface value)
> IBsonSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context,
> BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value)
> BsonExtensionMethods.ToBson(Object obj, Type nominalType,
> BsonBinaryWriterSettings writerSettings, IBsonSerializer serializer,
> Action`1 configurator, BsonSerializationArgs args) BsonExtensionMethods.ToBson[TNominalType](TNominalType obj, IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonBinaryWriterSettings writerSettings,
> Action`1 configurator, BsonSerializationArgs args) CyberGoodControllerTests.GetAll_CyberGoods_ReturnsList() line 30 --- End of stack trace from previous location --- ----- Inner Stack Trace ----- ObjectSerializer.SerializeDiscriminatedValue(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value, Type actualType) ObjectSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value) IBsonSerializer.Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, Object value) IBsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonSerializationContext context, Object value) BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeNormalMember(BsonSerializationContext
> context, Object obj, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
> BsonClassMapSerializer`1.SerializeMember(BsonSerializationContext
> context, Object obj, BsonMemberMap memberMap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think `BsonSerializer` can serialize/deserialize the value with `IActionResult` type.

Instead,

1. Cast `result` as [`OkObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0) type. And assert the `okResult` is not null to prove the action returns an `OkObjectResult`.
2. Extract `okResult.Value` and cast it as `List<CyberGood>` type. And assert the `bsonRes` is not null to prove that the value is `List<CyberGood>` type.
3. Lastly, you are able to perform the assertion for matching the counts.

```cs
IActionResult result = await service.GetAllCyberGoodAsync();
var okResult = result as OkObjectResult();

// Validate result returned as OkResult
Assert.NotNull(okResult);
var bsonRes = okResult.Value as List<CyberGood>;

// Assert bsonRes is List<CyberGood> type
Assert.NotNull(bsonRes);

// Assert
Assert.Equal(GetTestCyberGoods().Count, bsonRes.Count);
```

Comment: That's very weird for me but it just works! Thank you very much!